# Jmeter - django application non functional testing

Tags: django, jmeter

I'm thinking on using Jmeter for django applications. I basically wanted to carry out the following tests on my django application.

1) Performance testing
2) Load testing
3) Capacity testing
4) Stress testing

Will I be able to carry out all the testing methods in jmeter for my django app? I'm new here and yet to acquire basic knowledge on jmeter application.

Comment: you can use JMeter for your requirements. Start learning the product here http://jmeter.apache.org/. It has decent documentation. If you come across any specific issues, you can post the question. FYI, SO is not the place to teach whole subject by Q & A

Comment: I din't expect whole subject. But just wanted to have a clarity on whether django apps can be tested in jmeter application.

Comment: From my knowledge, JMeter can be used to test any web application irrespective of the programming language/framework that is used to built (you deal with HTTP packets). So, I strongly assume even the web application built using django also supported. please refer `What can I do with it?` section here http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: Will refer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, performance testing is a **testing practice**, load, capacity and stress testing are lesser subsets of performance testing.

When in comes to JMeter testing of web -  JMeter acts on [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) level so it doesn't know anything about underlying technology of the web application so from JMeter point of view there is no difference what is under the hood: plain HTML, ASP.NET, Java, Django, PHP, whatever so tread Django web application as "normal" web application and refer the following material:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)

The only point you can face is that Django web applications normally implement [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) protection via so called [csrf_token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/) so most likely you won't be able to record and replay your test scenario without modification (known as "correlation". See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide for details on how it can be bypassed